# Custom validation for people editor control

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-on-prem, clientpeoplepicker, validation-error

How to add custom validation for  in asp.net if the user adds more than one username an error message must appear that he can only add one user.
Thanks
Regard.

Comment: I think people editor has setting is itself to allow multiple users. If its set for just one user then by itself it will prompt user with a message.

Comment: You could achieve this using Client Side Rendering. But if you really just want to limit the input to one user, then like Asad said, there's already a built-in functionality for this.